# Java : How to find / know if the code has got any issues in that?

Tags: java

I have written a Custom Log4J Appender which is responsible to send the log message to a third party service asyncronsly

So this is expected to be called every millisecond

This is my Custom Appender code

I have ran **Findbugs** on this code , it didn't reported anything unusual.

but before releasing this code to production , how can i know if this code has got any issues with it .

Is there any tool for this purpose ?

please share your ideas on this , thanks in advance .

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

    public MyAppender() {

    }

    public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
        buffer.add(event);
        flushBuffer(buffer);
    }

    public void flushBuffer(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer) {
        for (Iterator<LoggingEvent> i = buffer.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            try {
                LoggingEvent logEvent = (LoggingEvent) i.next();
                String messageRecievied = (String) logEvent.getMessage();
                //System.out.println(messageRecievied);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @austin I disagree - he's asking "how do I find bugs in my code," not "please find bugs in my code"

Comment: There's no such tool AFAIK

Comment: Java itself catches most obvious errors itself and won't compile (im a big fan of statically typed languages for this). I can't even begin to imagine a utility that would catch all bugs

Comment: You are eating exceptions in your for loop

Comment: Scheduling this to happen every Millisecond seems a little optimistic ...

Comment: @DaveHowes why whats wrong in that ?

Comment: @SteveKuo , i dont have any other option the caller is itself a predefined method (append) which cant have throws block in it .

Answer (score 3):

**Test it.**

Figure out what the use cases are, including edge cases.
Make unit tests.

Think of any variables in the deployment environment that could break your code.
Create integration tests to make sure those scenarios all work.

Create a fake receiver and test it against that.
You'll need to create tests for your receiver to make sure it's validating properly.

Comment: Thanks , i was worried about the memory leaks .

Comment: @PreethiJain To find memory leaks you can write load tests and check how the memory behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to predict the result of arbitrary code with arbitrary input is [an NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-Complete) problem. Therefore, there is no 100% sure way to guarantee code doesn't have a problem with (at least before the heat-death of the universe. Thus, you're squarely in the realm of risk-management.

So what do you do?

**TEST**
Unit and system tests can help give you confidence that your code is without bugs. Use something like [JUnit](http://junit.org/) to do this. With such suites you can give particular inputs and check to make sure the output is valid. But note that this will only test against the inputs you've provided, and not against *any* input, and therefore even very good test suites may give you false confidence. Therefore, the second line of defense is...

**METRICS**
Be sure you're measuring and have visibility into everything you can. If you put new code into production and writes to your database increase by a factor of ten... you might have a problem. Or perhaps your error message velocity increases - or drops to nothing. You can't be sure of the health of your system unless you are monitoring key metrics. But what happens if something is going wrong?

**FEATURE CONTROLS**
In any complex system where you're adding new features, it's a good idea to have controls on those features. Think of this as a global toggle that will let you choose between old code pathways and new ones. For instance:

```
public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
    if (FeatureController.isActive(this.FEATURE_NAME)){
      ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
      buffer.add(event);
      flushBuffer(buffer);
    }
}
```

This lets you quickly shut off new features if they're causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot exist such a tool, otherwise it would be artificial intelligence and would write the whole code without needing you ;-)

But if possible write unit tests. With good unit tests, for many tasks you can deploy and it runs the first time without any bug. (The tool is called JUnit)

Second tool: [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) eclipse plugin:
It shows junit test coverage. do you have 80% or more of coverage? No? (Shame on you ;-))

Look at the src of appache log4j, i remember that they have some unit tests, maybe there are some for the existing appenders.

Comment: :) good one AlexWien , i dont want to lose my job due to such a tool existence .

Comment: my school teacher said 22 years ago that in future programs will written automatically, just a little of module arrangement. we still have our jobs...

Comment: Computer programmersare paid quite well. Why? Because it is a highly skilled (mostly) manual process. Which is ironic,  as they are in the business of automating things.

Comment: @Raedwald IDEs are quite comfortable today, many things are automated, think of the years where people coded assembler with paper and pencil.